# Convert $(x \land y) \vdash (y \land x)$ to $\vdash (x \land y \to y \land x)$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

We are given a proof system with rules

- Modus Ponens $p \to q, p \vdash q$
- Right implication introduction $q\to p \to q$
- Distributive implication introduction $p \to (q \to r) \to (p \to q) \to (p \to r)$

We need to convert a given valid proof of $(x \land y) \vdash (y \land x)$ to a proof of $\vdash (x \land y \to y \land x)$ with rules above and from the original proof (below) (the Deduction Theorem is not allowed)

- $x \land y$
- $x \land y \to y$ (conjuction elimination)
- $y$
- $x \land y \to x$ (conjuction elimination)
- $x$
- $ y \to x \to y \land x$ (conjuction introduction)
- $ x \to y \land x $  (Modus Ponens)
- $ y \land x $ (Modus Ponens again)

Comment: You’re basically done. You just need to actually write your conclusion while making note of the fact that you used the Deduction Theorem.

Comment: @RW_123,sorry I should have made it more clear which, it should not use the Deduction Theorem, only rules of the original proofs and 3 rules of our given proof system are allowed.

Comment: Apply the "recipe" provided by every proof of the Dedcution Th.

Comment: See [Wiki's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem#Example_of_conversion)